# Creating a new custom links section

Tags: visualforce, related-list, customization, custom-link

I've been given a requirement to change the name of the Custom Links section in Account details. Changing the section name through Edit Page is greyed out, according to SF help it's one of the standard fields that can't be changed.

I could add a new section and use formula fields to act as links, but 
a) people are used to going through the custom links creation process and 
b) the field names show up, which isn't wanted.

Is there a way to create a visualforce page that will display custom links as the custom links section does, that I could then add into a blank section on the page?

---

EDIT:

While looking for something else I found that custom links can be referenced as a value for the $Action global variable:

> `<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.name_of_custom_link)}">Name of custom link</apex:outputLink>`

However, this doesn't capture the additional features of a custom link. Is there a way to bring through the behaviour, height, scroll options and so on? That way I could create the section once as a visualforce object but any alterations users made to the links would come through automatically.

Comment: As far as I know, you CAN create a VF page to display links, but they would need to be hard-coded into the display (not a drag-and-drop layout change).  That being said, the formula-fields option has worked very well for us since it's declarative, and you can make quick updates and changes.  We use a naming convention of LABEL = ReportName, link = "GO"

Comment: It's that function of capturing Custom Links as created through Salesforce that I need, unfortunately. Or a way that I've missed to simply rename the existing section. If all that fails I do like your naming convention however, I might be able to sell that as an alternative to the users if they can't have what they want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new section which mirrors the behaviour of the Custom Links section was not possible, but I did succeed in changing the name with a css hack:

```
#head_1_ep_j_id0_Account{
color: transparent;
}

#head_1_ep_j_id0_Account:after {
content: "Predefined Reports";
color: #27282E;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin-left: -84px;
}
```

Not ideal, and vulnerable to Salesforce changing how classes are named, but it works.